# $10$ distinct color balls and we want to divide them into $3$ identical boxes with hard restrictions and probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

> We have $10$ distinct color balls and we want to divide them into $3$ identical boxes .We decide that two of the groups can contain at most $3$ balls and the rest one contain at most $4$ balls. Moreover, there are two balls called $A$ and $B$ in $10$ balls.
>
> $1-)$ How many ways are there to distribute these $10$ balls to $3$ groups obeying size restriction of groups and $A$ and $B$ are in the same box?
>
> $2-)$ What is the probability that $A$ and $B$ are in the same boxes obeying size restriction of boxes?
>
> $3-)$  How many ways are there to distribute these $10$ balls to $3$ groups obeying size restriction of groups and $A$ and $B$ are not in the same box?
>
> $4-)$ What is the probability that $A$ and $B$ are not in the same boxes obeying size restriction of boxes?
>
> $5-)$ Solve the foregoing $4$ questions if the number of balls is $7$ instead of $10$.

Solution

$1-)$ $$\bigg (\frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}}{2!}=140 \bigg)+ \bigg (\frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2}}{2!} =280\bigg )=420$$

$2-)$ $$\bigg (\frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}}{2!}+ \frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2}}{2!} \bigg )/\frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}}{2!}=42/168$$

$3-)$ $$\frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}}{2!}-420 =2100-420=1680$$

$4-)$ By using $3$ and $4$ , $$1-42/168=126/168$$

$5-)$ I could not solve this part because of low number of balls, and I do not know how to distribute.

Are my solutions correct? If not, can you correct me and help for $5$?

Comment: I would think that $10-7=3=1+1+1$ suggests that you should decrease the restriction on each box by $1$ so that they have at most $2,2,3$ balls.

Comment: I think all of them are wrong unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

First question:

The first term is incorrect. It should be,

$ \displaystyle \binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}=280$

Unlike second term, it should not be divided by $2!$ as the boxes having $3$ balls each are different groups - one of them has $A$ and $B$ and the other is without them.

So the answer should be $560$

Second question:

The denominator, as you mentioned, $ \displaystyle \binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4} / 2! = 2100$

So the probability is $\displaystyle \frac{560}{2100} = \frac{4}{15}$

Now you can use above results to solve $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Coming to the question if there are $7$ balls instead of $10$, you can break it into cases: $i$) three groups with $1, 2, 4$ balls $ii$) three groups with $2, 2, 3$ balls $iii$) $1, 3, 3$ balls

Comment: I agree with you in the first solution , but why  did you solve the probability part like combinatorics questions ? As far as i know we behave all as distinguishable in prbability questions ,so dividing by 2! does not make sense to me

Comment: @Bulbasaur  all we are doing is to make $3$ non-empty heaps with given constraints. We then multiply by $3!$ to assign these heaps to different boxes. As $3!$ is common in both numerator and denominator, I have not explicitly shown that.

Comment: for part 5 , why dont we think the case where $3,4$ balls

Comment: Yes that can be an interpretation too. If you read the first question, it says - How many ways are there to distribute these $10$ balls to $3$ _groups_ obeying size restriction of groups and A and B are in the same box? So I assume that there has to be $3$ groups.

Comment: @Bulbasaur After my last comment, is it clear to you that if you do not divide by $2!$, that would be wrong?

Comment: @MathLover oh sorry i forgot to write answer , my bad. yes it is clear but i think that a litle edition to show $3!$ may be good for showing to OP that when we work over probability , then identical objects are seen as distinct..$+1$